# MySql Full Index search not working

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I set the example code here

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6aa9ec/1
>
> Below mentioned DB query used for searching the word Samsung but its not working

```
SELECT `idREQUEST`, `USER_NAME`, `idCATEGORY`, `TITLE`, `DESCRIPTION`, `IMAGE_URL1`, `IMAGE_URL2`, `IMAGE_URL3`, `POST_DATE`
    FROM `requests`
    WHERE MATCH (`TITLE`,`DESCRIPTION`) AGAINST('Samsung')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Boolean Full-Text Searches`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

```
SELECT `idREQUEST`,
`USER_NAME`, 
`idCATEGORY`, 
`TITLE`,
`DESCRIPTION`, 
`IMAGE_URL1`, 
`IMAGE_URL2`,
`IMAGE_URL3`, 
`POST_DATE`
FROM `requests`
WHERE MATCH (`TITLE`,`DESCRIPTION`) AGAINST('+Samsung' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

> According to docs
>
> MySQL can perform boolean full-text searches using
>   the IN BOOLEAN MODE modifier. With this modifier, certain characters
>   have special meaning at the beginning or end of words in the search
>   string. In the following query, the + operator indicate that a
>   word is required to be present, respectively, for a match to
>   occur.

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6aa9ec/20)

Comment: I think the performance of this one is better than using `where like` and `or` clause since it's implemented by default. Although i'm not so sure. Any idea about the performance @M Khalid Junaid??

Comment: @Payam yes performance is better than like because of full text index usage

Comment: thanks its working... Can you please look at this issue also http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89e95/1
I want to get the last message of the chat but its returning only the time not the message and message id

Comment: @pritinarang if you have another question its better to ask a new question i will look in to your next problem if you provide brief regarding your problem in new question

Comment: I have to wait 90 minutes as per SO for that please help me.

Comment: @pritinarang i guess this [*Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89e95/4) will solve your problem ,i have used self joins to get the recent message according to your conditions

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid please look at the same issue please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654572/mysql-group-by-where-date-time-max I have to group by part having maximum time row

Answer (score 0):

This query looks for tiles and descriptions which the value is merely 'Samsung' But there are no entries in your table which are only 'Samsung'. Hence I'd suggest you to use `%`

```
SELECT `idREQUEST`, `USER_NAME`, `idCATEGORY`, `TITLE`, `DESCRIPTION`,
`IMAGE_URL1`, `IMAGE_URL2`, `IMAGE_URL3`, `POST_DATE`
 FROM `requests`
  where  `TITLE` like '%Samsung%' or `DESCRIPTION` like '%Samsung%'
```

[This is the link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6aa9ec/13/0)

Comment: Yes @Payam I can but my requirement with full text anyway Can you please look at this issue also sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89e95/1 I want to get the last message of the chat but its returning only the time not the message and message id

Comment: @pritinarang is it ok if I change the query structure? I don't see why would you use an if statement in it.

Comment: if is used for getting counter party